# PATCH request for web api not processed in 2008 R2 server IIS-7.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, windows-server-2008-r2

I have developed a web api with HTTPPATCH. I am using Fiddler to test the web api. In my local host I am not facing any issue and able to process patch request successfully. But when I am hosting the same in 2008 R2 server where my IIS version is 7.5. I am not able to process Patch request using the fiddler. I am getting error code 400, Proxy server closed.

Additionally I have GET, POST and DELETE request as well. These request are able to process successfully.

Comment: You mean you changed IIS Server? From localhost to another Server PC?

Comment: Yes, I have visual studio in my windows 7 OS. After development completed I am trying to publish the web api in windows server 2008 R2.

Comment: Ok thanks, but before you deployed it to a server, Is your server IIS set up correctly?

Comment: yes, I have no issue to process GET,POST or DELETE request. I am only facing issue in PATCH request

Answer (score 0):

Deployment to IIS Server:

```
1.) Set up your IIS correctly.
2.) Check username credentials folder permission.
3.) check application pools framework for your project after your project paste into IIS server.
4.) Check Browsing Directory if enabled.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to update the link of API using new server. In your project there's a reference service option then you can change it in there or update service

Comment: Before that make sure that your API is running, if not then you got a big problem.

Comment: If you want to run your WEB API then write click asmx file ==> Browse

Comment: Yes some what correct. But I am only trying to find out how to configure IIS for PATCH request. Everything is fine as far as GET,POST or DELETE is concerned.

Comment: http://timanelmer.byethost17.com/2015/09/enable-patchputdelete-request-on-iis/?i=1 take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I used HTTPS with PORT 443 instead of HTTP for PATCH request and Its working as expected.

https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/83648-odata-web-api-2-patch-not-working